# fhir.executeBundle replacing resource id...How to prevent this?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, hl7-fhir

I am using this [Java code](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/fhir-bundles#healthcare-execute-bundle-java) to upload a resource to a FHIRstore.
The resource is as follows

```
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "id": "bundle-transaction",
  "meta": {
    "lastUpdated": "2018-03-11T11:22:16Z"
  },
  "type": "transaction",
  "entry": [
    {
      "resource": {
        "resourceType": "Patient", "id" : 123456,
        "name": [
          {
            "family": "Smith",
            "given": [
              "Darcy"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "gender": "female",
        "address": [
          {
            "line": [
              "123 Main St."
            ],
            "city": "Anycity",
            "state": "CA",
            "postalCode": "12345"
          }
        ]
      },
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
    "url": "Patient"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But the id i am using(123456) is getting replaced by a hexadecimal number.

This does not happen while using [fhirstores.import method](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.datasets.fhirStores/import)
Is there any way to stop executeBundle method from replacing my id...as i want to use custom id in my resource?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're performing a transaction, the effect is going to be the same as if you were POSTing the resources individually.  On a POST, the *server* determines the resource id.  On a regular POST, the id is just ignored or raises an error.  Within a transaction, the id is used to manage resolution of references across the transaction, but the server still chooses what the id will be of the persisted resources (and updates all references accordingly).  If you want to control the resource id values within a transaction, use PUT rather than POST.  (Note that not all servers will allow an 'upsert' - i.e. a PUT that performs a create at a specific resource location.)  For details, see http://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#upsert.

Comment: if the server doesn't allow upsert with PUT, do we have no other way to control id values?

Comment: Nope.  Servers generally control ids to prevent multiple clients from accidentally posting different objects to the same place and/or because their persistence technologies relies on a specific identifier pattern (e.g. integers, guids, etc.)  You're free to include 'your' id as an "identifier" you can use in searching the server, but unless the server is designed for and configured to allow you to upsert, you can't control the id it uses.

Comment: The Google Cloud Healthcare API allows you to choose whether or not each FHIR store allows upserts by setting the "enable_update_create" flag.